# Check comma separated string in comma separated column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a string `searchval = "php,java,html"`.

I want to check any of the comma separated value in string exist in column keyword in my below table.

My table

```
id     keyword
-----------------------------
1      java,php
2      jquery, javascript
3      java
4      php,jquery
```

Any of the searchval(comma separated) value match the keyword(comma separated) should return the id.

So the result should be:

```
1 (java,php is there),
3 (java is there),
4 (php is there)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you see `find_in_set`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry actually I tried this first in mysql

Answer (score 7):

You can easily convert a comma separated list into an array, then use Postgres' [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) to test for containment:

```
select id
from the_table
where string_to_array(keyword,',') && array['php','java','html'];
```

The overlaps operator `&&` checks if the array created from the keyword list contains elements from the array on the right hand side.

Online example: http://rextester.com/VNWP17762

Comment: Lol!.. I liked the indirect way of saying "bad design"

Comment: @KaushikNayak . . . I don't think the indirect way was direct enough.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, an important advice: **do not** store comma separated strings in a column in database. It makes processing unnecessarily harder. You should rather consider creating a separate keyword table and have a foreign key on your table on id column.

You could convert the strings to ARRAY and do an overlaps operation.But, to check value by value, you would need to `UNNEST` it for comparison.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10ca8/28)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (id int, keyword varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (id, keyword)
VALUES
    (1, 'java,php'),
    (2, 'jquery, javascript'),
    (3, 'java'),
    (4, 'php,jquery')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id, 
       string_agg(lang, ',') AS keyword 
FROM   t, 
       unnest(string_to_array(keyword, ',')) AS k(lang) 
WHERE  lang = ANY ( string_to_array('php,java,html', ',') ) 
GROUP  BY id 
ORDER  BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/10ca8/28/0)**:

```
| id |  keyword |
|----|----------|
|  1 | java,php |
|  3 |     java |
|  4 |      php |
```